# Is this machine still operational?

Tags: legal-status, wo2010140158a1

I wanted to check if this machine still operational and if the patent is still in effect?

I tried a Google search but couldn't find many details about it.

Answer (score 1):

Google only provides a limited amount of information about the patent status. This is a PCT (International) application, so you need to check multiple sources (WIPO/Patentscope, Espacenet and USPTO) in order to find the status of the application in all relevant countries.

For instance the USPTO [Public Pair](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) database has the US application ([US 2012/0065024 A1](http://www.google.com/patents/US20120065024)) legal status as:

```
01-12-2015  Mail Abandonment for Failure to Respond to Office Action
```

However, this could change in the next 6 months if the inventor decides to revive the application.

To find the status of other international applications, check the [National Phase](https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/detail.jsf?docId=WO2010140158&recNum=1&tab=NationalPhase&maxRec=&office=&prevFilter=&sortOption=&queryString=) tab in Patentscope:

```
Office                    Entry Date  National Number  National Status
India                     08.11.2011  8649/DELNP/2011 
United States of America  17.11.2011  13320971         Published: 15.03.2012
```

The only other international application is India patent application 8649/DELNP/2011. I am not familiar with the Indian patent system, and there is no status listed. Someone else on this site might be more familiar with that patent office.

Comment: Also, the machine being operational is an entirely different question than whether the patent is in effect. I would think the Patent SE site wouldn't be the ideal place to ask about whether the actual machine is still in use.